# Proof of a formula for Hilbert Series of finitely generated graded rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $S$ be a graded $k$-algebra generated by homogeneous elements $f_1,\dots,f_r$ with degrees $d_1,\dots,d_r$. The following is Proposition 1.9 in "Mukai, An Introduction to Invariants and Moduli" (with minor changes!):

> The Hilbert series of S is equal to
>   $$ P(t) = \frac{F(t)}{(1-t^{d_1})\dots(1-t^{d_r})},$$
>   for some $F(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t].$

I think there is a flaw in Mukai's proof ($f_i$'s are not necessary nonzero-divisor in $S/k[f_1,\dots,f_{i-1}]$ and then the map $h\mapsto f_i h$ is not injective in this ring and induction does not work...).

There is also a proof in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial) for the case $d_1=d_2=\dots =d_r= 1$, but I want a proof for the general case.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to Atiyah-Macdonald or Matsumura.

Comment: @ThomasShelby I found this in Matsumura, Theorem 13.2. Thanks!

Comment: Mukai doesn't use what you say. He uses that the multiplication by $f_r$ is injective on $S$ (which is not every graded $k$-algebra, its a subalgebra of a polynomial ring, hence an integral domain).

Comment: @user26857 In Mukai's setting $S$ is a subalgebra of a polynomial ring but after going to the quotient $S/k[f_1]\equiv k[f_2,\dots]$ in the induction step, the resulting graded ring may not be an integral domain. And so the induction doesn't work.

Comment: Actually the quotient he gets is $S/f_rS$. The weak point of his proof is when he says that this quotient is isomorphic to a subring of $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ generated $f_1,\dots,f_{r-1}$.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you are right. This is exactly what i wanted to say.